# want to write in a file what is actually in Textarea in java

Tags: java

Suppose in textarea the lines are,

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
```

In file it writes

```
This is the first line. This is the second line.
```

where is my newlines and extra spaces in the second line.

I used getText() to get the value from the textfield.

Comment: Try using JTextPane instead of JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

> I used getText() to get the value from the textfield.

Don't create your own method. Instead use the `write(...)` method provided by the `JTextArea API`:

```
textArea.write(...);
```

and it will use the appropriate newline string for your OS.

Answer (score -1):

You can add "\n"

```
textArea.write(... + "\n");
```

Comment: -1, the write(...) method writes out the entire contents of the text area including the new line string for each line in the text area. What is the point of adding a single new line string at the end of the file?